# Python - reply to all top-level comments in a particular thread

Tags: python, bots, reddit

I'm looking to write a simple Python 3 bot for reddit which will **reply to all top-level comments in a thread with a particular title, in a particular subreddit.**

For example:

- Bot scans /r/testsubreddit for the most recent post with the title 'bot trigger'
- Bot replies to all top-level comments in that thread with a random string from a predefined list

What's the best way to go around doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably starting with the `PRAW` docs and attempting something actually. There is lots of sample code online.

Comment: You don't need it to have specific top-level commenting in the code. You just need to understand how to build the bot. AFAIK the `PRAW` docs show how to deal with top level comments. Do some more digging. This took me under a [minute](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/comments.html?highlight=top%20level)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a valid question. You asked "How do I go about doing this?", not "Build this for me", which is certainly a valid question for a programming Q&A website.

I see two possible routes you could go:

1. Using a library of your choice (I would use `requests`) to make some network calls to the [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api). There's a lot to digest on that page, but to get started with OAuth, which you need in order to make a bot that's more than just read-only, check out [this guide](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example).
2. Using an existing framework, such as [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I love using PRAW, although again, if you've never done anything like this before, it's kind of tricky to figure out. Follow along with some of the examples under Quick Start -> Common Tasks to get your feet wet. I think you'll find it relatively straight forward after first writing some basic scripts to get submissions, get comments from submissions, and automate comment replies.

After you've gotten oriented, your basic algorithm is simple:

```
Get your auth headers (or Reddit instance if you're using PRAW)
Get the submission you want to target
Get all of the top-level comments on that submission
Loop through them and reply however you want
```

If you get stuck, you can ask PRAW questions at http://reddit.com/r/redditdev, or come talk to me at my sub, http://reddit.com/r/redditscripting.

Once you have some initial code going, your fellow programmers will respond a little more warmly to your requests for help :-)

Happy coding!